# Send records count from server to breeze when custom query is used

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, breeze, hottowel

```
return Repository.Clients.OrderByDescending(cl => cl.ID).AsQueryable().Skip(startIndex).Take(pageSize);
```

I am executing a custom breeze query in web api and want the total no of records fetched on client side. How can I send the records count from server to client. Since its a custom query, data.inlineCount will not work here that is usually used with the breeze query.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a complex object on the server to pass back with the results and an inlineCount property on it so that Breeze interprets it correctly -

```
public class returnResult
{
    public returnResult()
    {
        Results = new List<MyObject>();
    }

    public int InlineCount{ get; set; }

    public List<MyObject> Results { get; set; }
}
```

And stuff your results into the results property and the count in the inlineCount property.

In fact you could do this with any property name and just pull the property out in your query results -

```
return manager.executeQuery(query).then(querySucceeded);

function querySucceeded(data) {
    var inlineCount = data.totalRecords;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I had created a Notmapped property in my entity class but I had to set the value of that property for every record (as I need the records count while paging through the records) which I don't want. Is it possible to send an output parameter from breeze to server, set that value on server & use it on client side ?

Comment: You missed the point - don't set it on each object, set it onto the object that you are returning, which contains 'results' and another property called 'inlineCount' which is only set once.  Breeze interprets your 'results' as objects and thinks your server is returning inlineCount and leaves it alone

Comment: Instead of using skip & take on server, I have added these two clauses in the breeze query. This works as well.